# (rm/xargs) purposefully slowing down the number of arguments passed to a command per second?

Tags: bash, posix

I have a script that cleans up some folders by path. I have hardened it as much as i can, but there is still a 0.001% chance it will delete other folders i don't want it to. Those respective folders have many files so i will "catch" it in time and hit Ctrl+C.

However there's a problem, even by piping with rm -v the command still runs too quickly for my eye

How to slow it down? Either the number of arguments passed through the pipe, or the find or rm command itself? I need a number of about ~10 per second, doesn't need to be precise.

`find 'xxxxxxx' -path "*xxxx/*xxxx" | sed -e 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs rm -rv`

Comment: If you determine this by the number of files, why don't you just auto-abort if the count is high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe it to a `while read ...` loop instead of `xargs`, then add a 0.1-second sleep before each file, equaling ~10 files per second.

```sh
find 'xxxxxxx' -path "*xxxx/*xxxx" \
  | sed -e 's/.*/"&"/' \
  | while read file; do
      echo "Removing: $file"
      sleep 0.1
      rm -r "$file"
    done
```

Potentially better option: since you're interested in specific directories, you could make `find` only match directories (using `-type d`), then pause before each one of them for a bit longer, then delete all files without delay if not interrupted.

```sh
# though you'd probably have to adjust the -path pattern
find 'xxxxxxx' -path "*xxxx/*xxxx" -type d \
  | sed -e 's/.*/"&"/' \
  | while read directory; do
      echo "About to remove directory: $directory"
      sleep 2
      rm -r "$directory"
    done
```